# Pandas: fetch rows that continuously have a similar value

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like so..

```
      id     time    status
      --     ----    ------
      a       1        T
      a       2        F
      b       1        T
      b       2        T
      a       3        T
      a       4        T
      b       3        F
      b       4        T
      b       5        T
```

I would like to fetch the ids that continuously have the status 'T' for a certain threshold number of times (say 2 in this case).

Thus the fetched rows would be...

```
    id   time   status
    --   ----   ------
    b      1      T
    b      2      T
    a      3      T
    a      4      T
    b      4      T
    b      5      T
```

I can think of an iterative solution. What I am looking for is something more pandas/sql like. I think an order by `id` and then `time` followed by a group by first by `id` and then `status` should work, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `T` and count consecutive values with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to original - get counts per consecutive groups. Then compare by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) chain both mask by bitwise `AND`:

```
N = 2
m1 = df['status'].eq('T')
g = df['status'].ne(df['status'].shift()).cumsum()
m2 = g.map(g.value_counts()).ge(N)

df = df[m1 & m2]
print (df)
  id  time status
2  b     1      T
3  b     2      T
4  a     3      T
5  a     4      T
7  b     4      T
8  b     5      T
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(m1=m1, g=g, counts=g.map(g.value_counts()), m2=m2))
  id  time status     m1  g  counts     m2
0  a     1      T   True  1       1  False
1  a     2      F  False  2       1  False
2  b     1      T   True  3       4   True
3  b     2      T   True  3       4   True
4  a     3      T   True  3       4   True
5  a     4      T   True  3       4   True
6  b     3      F  False  4       1  False
7  b     4      T   True  5       2   True
8  b     5      T   True  5       2   True
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a little?

Comment: @SudeepamPandey - Can you be more specific?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th lines from your code are a bit cryptic. Could you please explain what exactly is happening in them?

Comment: @SudeepamPandey - `g` is for consecutive groups, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59491759/distinct-grouped-cumulative-sum-on-duplicates-group/59491788#59491788) and last `g.value_counts()` counts groups and add `map` for counts of original series `g`, added some details to answer.